# How to make a label (NSTextField) auto-resize by content programmatically?

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout, nstextfield

Can I make an multi-line-NSTextField object auto-resize by its content?

For example, I want to make the object's width fixed, but its height fit its content. How should I generate the layout constraints then?

Comment: In addition to the suggestions below you could also just use auto layout and get all that functionality for free..

Comment: @Abdrew, i have update your answer please follow??

Comment: @Jay I know I can use IB. I wonder how to achieve that by code :)

Comment: @AndrewChang Well, just use auto-layout in code then?! ;-) Set the *Content Compression Resistance Priority* high enough and it'll expand auto-magically

Comment: @HussainShabbir An answer combining Hussain's and Parag's would be perfect! Hussain's solution is the one I will definitely use in my current project!(And thank you very much, Hussain!!!!) Meanwhile Parag's answer is more compatible (more complex, though). Considering most people, I choose Parag's answer as accepted one.

Comment: @Jay "Content Compression Resistance Priority"? I haven't read this term in the auto-layout documents I have read before. Could you please point out which document I should read?

Comment: @AndrewChang Just open any view or control in the Interface Builder/Editor in Xcode and you'll spot the sliders in the Inspector!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can use [NS(Attributed)String+Geometrics](https://github.com/jerrykrinock/CategoriesObjC) category.

> NS(Attributed)String+Geometrics is a pair or reuseable categories (on
>   NSString and NSAttributedString) which you can add to your projects,
>   providing simple methods to get the width and height required for text
>   drawing.

[image: http://www.sheepsystems.com/sourceCode/sourceStringGeometrics.html]

Comment: I wonder why categories like that are not part of MacOS. Every control Apple makes available is half cooked to the bone. WTF! THANKS

Answer (score 7):

Follow the below steps:-

1) Select the `NSTextField` then inside `interface builder->AttributeIsnpector->set control to LineBreak-word wrap-> set state-> Enabled`

2) Implement below code :-

```
-(void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj
{
   //if you want to width to change then uncomment below
    //    CGFloat width=[[self.txtFld cell] cellSizeForBounds:self.txtFld.bounds].width;
        CGFloat heigth=[[self.txtFld cell] cellSizeForBounds:self.txtFld.bounds].height;
        [self.txtFld setFrameSize:NSMakeSize(160, heigth+10)];
}
```